# Balanced Language, 2 Non-Terminal Symbols, List Comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

So, I was reading a book, "An Introduction to Formal Language Theory" and it describes a language `L(G) = {a^n ++ b^n | n > 0}`.

It has the following productions:

```
S -> ab | aSb
```

And so would produce the following language:

```
a, ab, aabb, aaabbb, ...
```

I was wondering how I could use Haskell's list comprehension to create this language. I know I can do list comprehension with strings, but I'm pretty much of a beginner and wasn't sure how I could get an infinite list like I would like of these strings.

I'm imagining something like:

```
[ x ++ y | x <- ["a","aa",..] y <- ["b","bb",..]]
```

Comment: This is not doing exactly what you think it is. How about `[ replicate n 'a' ++ replicate n 'b' | n <- [1..] ]`? That seems like the most faithful translation...

Comment: "a" is not part of that language.

Comment: The direct translation to Perl 6 `'ab',-> \S { "a{S}b" } … *`, but what you are trying is more similar to `[Z~] ('a' Xx 1..*), ('b' Xx 1..*)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working from the production rule,

```
S -> ab | aSb
```

we could write

```
s = ["ab"] ++ [ "a" ++ x ++ "b" | x <- s ]
```

so that

```
~> take 5 s
["ab","aabb","aaabbb","aaaabbbb","aaaaabbbbb"]
it :: [[Char]]
```

Your attempt could work with a small edit,

```
[ x ++ y | x <- ["a","aa",..] | y <- ["b","bb",..]]
```

so that it uses [Parallel List Comprehensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?#parallel-list-comprehensions) extension (`:set -XParallelListComp` in GHCi), except for the enumerations. But this is simple to fix,

```
[ x ++ y | x <- [replicate n 'a' | n <- [1..]] 
         | y <- [replicate n 'b' | n <- [1..]]]
```

Comment: Quick followup, I noticed that when I wrote `s = ["ab"] ++ [ "a" ++ x ++ "b" | x <- s ]` in the ghci, it throws an error, but if I put it in test.hs and then :l test, it works! Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: what was the error? did you try using `let`, like `let s = ...` (you have to, in the case you have an older version installed).

Comment: ah, it said `<interactive>:2:3: parse error on input ‘=’`; but, if you're right, if I use let it works!

Comment: `["ab"] ++` could be written as `"ab" :`

Comment: @4castle yes, but, it's one less thing to be dealing with, without the `:`. another take on it could be, "lists" are `[...]` and `++`, on a higher level (i.e. viewed as a monoid); `:` is an implementational detail (cf. Clojure's "lists" impl'd as shallow trees). third is, `++` is what corresponds to `|` in production rules (not `:`).